# JQuery Inputmask breaks when using currency values of 1 million and above

Tags: jquery-inputmask

So I have a currency inputmask defined like this:

```
    $(".value_price").inputmask('decimal', {
        'alias': 'numeric',
        'groupSeparator': ',',
        'autoGroup': true,
        'digits': 2,
        'radixPoint': ",",
        'digitsOptional': false,
        'allowMinus': false,
        'prefix': 'R$ ',
        'placeholder': '00',
        'removeMaskOnSubmit' : true,
        'numericInput': true,
        'greedy': false,
        'skipOptionalPartCharacter': "",
        'clearMaskOnLostFocus': false
    });
```

Mostly it works just fine, but I've encountered a weird problem that I don't know if it is a bug or I'm just doing it wrong.

If I run `$('#value').val(149700)`. The masked input shows the value `R$ 1.497,00` correctly, that's the expected.

But, if I run `$('#value').val(1497000)` (one more zero), now the masked input shows `R$41.970,00` Instead of the expected `R$ 14.970,00`

The one extra zero, broke the prefix (no more space after it) and somehow changed the order of the numbers??

Also, when I try to run `$('#value').inputmask('unmaskedvalue')` on the broken input, it returns the raw value, still masked.

Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong here?